# Leaflet: How to toggle GeoJSON feature properties from a single collection?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a single GeoJSON object that contains over 2000+ features and each feature is part of one category (i.e. "Electrical", "Military", etc). There are a total of about **38** categories.

> Here's the schema example of my collection:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"category":"Electrical","Name":"Plant No 1"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[81.73828125,62.59334083012024]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"category":"Electrical","Name":"Plane No 2"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[94.5703125,58.722598828043374]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"category":"Military","Name":"Base 1"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[104.4140625,62.91523303947614]}}
```

> Here's my L.geoJson function that iterates through the
>   collection:

```
var allPoints = L.geoJson(myCollection, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(popTemplate, feature.properties));
    },
    "stylel": function(feature){
        return { "color": legend[feature.properties.category]
    }
}}).addTo(map);
```

**How can I assign each `category` property to my L.control function so the user can toggle on/off the various categories from the collection?** I could do this if I made each category a dataset and an individual geoJSOn layer, but that's too much work to do all 38 categories.

My attempt:

```
L.control.layers({
    'Street Map': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets').addTo(map)
},{
    'Electrical': myCollection[feature.properties.category["Electrical"]],
    'Military': myCollection[feature.properties.category["Military"]]
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply assign your layers within the `onEachFeature` function. You could even automate the creation of Layer Groups for each category.

Result:

```js
var categories = {},
    category;

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(popTemplate, feature.properties));
    category = feature.properties.category;
    // Initialize the category array if not already set.
    if (typeof categories[category] === "undefined") {
        categories[category] = [];
    }
    categories[category].push(layer);
}

// Use function onEachFeature in your L.geoJson initialization.

var overlays = {},
    categoryName,
    categoryArray;

for (categoryName in categories) {
    categoryArray = categories[categoryName];
    overlays[categoryName] = L.layerGroup(categoryArray);
}

L.control.layers(basemaps, overlays).addTo(map);
```

EDIT: replaced `overlays` to be a mapping instead of an array.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of assigning the layers within the onEachFeature function instead of automating it? This may be an easier method for me to grasph at the moment.

Comment: OK, I got this one working (automated) but need some help printing the names of the categories next to the checkbox in the control. Right now, only numbers are there. But the toggling does work. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, `overlays` should have been a mapping rather than an array. I will correct the above code to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your GeoJSON collection and create multiple L.GeoJSON layers, one per category and add them as overlays to your L.Control.Layers instance.

```
var controlLayers = L.control.layers({
    'Street Map': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets').addTo(map)
}).addTo(map);

// Object to store category layers
var overlays = {};

// Iterate the collection
collection.features.forEach(function (feature) {

    var category = feature.properties.category;

    // Check if there's already an overlay for this category
    if (!overlays[category]) {

        // Create and store new layer in overlays object
        overlays[category] = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
            'onEachFeature': function () {},
            'style': function () {}
        });

        // Add layer/title to control
        controlLayers.addOverlay(overlays[category], category); 
    }

    // Add feature to corresponding layer
    overlays[category].addData(feature);
});
```

Here's an example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zv2xwv?p=preview

Comment: Thanks ,for some reason I could not get it working with mapbox maps. Either way, thanks for your help.