# Filtering a geojson Layer in Leaflet not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a geojson layer in leaflet that I wish to filter by year. This geojson layer was created from a geojson file, using pointToLayer.

The problem is, I'm not sure if this geoJsonLayer is an array? I am very confused about it's data structure, and thus, how to filter it.  When I `console.log` it, the data is nested like so:

`Object { options: Object, _layers: Object, _leaflet_id: 259, _initHooksCalled: true, _map: Object }`

Clicking on _layers, I'm able to get a list of objects (these are the points I currently am seeing displayed on my map).  If I click on one of the objects, I'm able to access a property called "Feature", which has a property called "Properties", which has a list of attributes:

```
info_city: Milwaukee

info_count: 1

info_date: 2002
```

This property called "info_date", is the field I want to filter by.

I've tried to unsuccessfully `console.log` the properties from `geoJsonLayers.residents` using `geoJsonLayers.residents.features.properties`.

I've tried to filter using:

```
function filterByYear(data, year) {
  f = data.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.properties.info_date == year;
  });
  return f;
}


filterByYear(geoJsonLayers.residents, 2009);
```

The problem is that I think the above method works for an array, but my data somehow seems to NOT be an a standard array once I converted my geojson file into a geoJsonLayer.  It's also not a string/numeric issue because I've tried both options.

I've also tried something along the lines of:

```
var points = L.geoJson(geoJsonLayers.residents, {
            filter: function(feature, layer) {
                console.log(geoJsonLayers.residents)
                console.log(points)
                return feature.properties.info_date === 2010;
            }
        });
```

Comment: filter is array method and what you are getting is object.

Comment: so, what should I do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**try something like this**

```
var arr = [];//this array to hold your filterred object
geoJsonLayers.eachLayer(function(layer){
if(layer.feature.properties.info_date === 2010){
arr.push(layer)
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `L.geoJSON` factory builds a Leaflet Layer Group object. It is definitely not a regular `Array`.

If you wish to get an array of the child layers in that Group, you can use [`points.getLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-getlayers). You can also directly map them / apply a callback function on each child layer, by using [`points.eachLayer(cb)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-eachlayer) as shown in Aksav padwal's answer.

As you noticed, the `L.geoJSON` factory automatically added your GeoJSON data into the `feature` member of each child layer.

Now if you wish to filter the child layers so that you can display them or not on the map, you should rather build as many Layer Groups as necessary, possibly while the `L.geoJSON` factory is parsing your GeoJSON data, so that you can add to / remove from map those layer groups.

See: [leaflet map, getting specific data of geojson file with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545791/leaflet-map-getting-specific-data-of-geojson-file-with-button?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Note that `L.geoJSON` option [`filter`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson-filter) works only at instantiation or when adding data.