# Jquery Leaflet marker layer control for dynamic custom icons with clustering plugin

Tags: jquery, leaflet

EDIT 2 - Taking a swing at incorporating @ghybs plugin. Not working, but it's an attempt.

```
//define clustering layer 
var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

var overlays = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) {
  overlays['Group ' + i] = L.featureGroup.subGroup(
    parentGroup,
    getArrayOfMarkers()
  ).addTo(map);
}
L.control.layers(null, overlays, {
  collapsed: false,
}).addTo(map);


//creates markers and popups for each json dataset
function getArrayOfMarkers(){
    var result = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i )
{

  var popup = '<br/><b>Sample Name:</b> '+ markers[i]["Sample Name"] +
              '<br/><b>Location Description:</b> ' + markers[i]["Location Description"] +
              '<br/><b>Date Taken:</b> ' + markers[i]["Date"] +
              '<br/><b>Classification:</b> ' + markers[i]["Classification"]

  result.push(L.marker( [markers[i].Lattitude, markers[i].Longitude], {icon: icons[markers[i]["Classification"]]})
                  .bindPopup( popup ));

return result;
}
}
```

EDIT - Previously marked as a duplicate and pointed to this thread:

[Using several Marker Cluster Groups displays overlapping Clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544086/using-several-marker-cluster-groups-displays-overlapping-clusters)

Which is great! That is what I am looking for. But I am still lost on how to incorporate that with the multiple dynamically created icons. (Which ISN'T discussed in the other thread.)  I have very little skill in this department.

---

I have managed to create custom marker icons based on a value coming from my json. But that incorporates all of the markers into one layer. I would like to implement layer control based on the marker types, but I'm not sure how to make that work with the clustering plugin.

Can layercontrol be used with the clustering?

Layer control examples:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/55/

Possible place to implement?

```
var m = L.marker( [markers[i].Lattitude, markers[i].Longitude], {icon: icons[markers[i]["Classification"]]})
                      .bindPopup( popup );
```

The desired end state would be a layer control icon on the map that allows you to display any combination of the four layers. [Source, Blank, Background, Unknown]

I'm going to keep attempting to get something to work, but here's to hoping someone here sees a simple solution.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample Locations</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

    <script charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>

 <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.2.4/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-tyPum7h2h36X52O2gz+Pe8z/3l+Y9S1yEUscbVs5r5aEY5dFmP1WWRY/WLLElnFHa+k1JBQZSCDGwEAnm2IxAQ=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

<body>
  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>

<style>
  #basemaps-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 400;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  #basemaps {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<div id="basemaps-wrapper" class="leaflet-bar">
  <select name="basemaps" id="basemaps" onChange="changeBasemap(basemaps)">


    <option value="Topographic">Topographic</option>
    <option value="Streets">Streets</option>
    <option value="NationalGeographic">National Geographic</option>
    <option value="Oceans">Oceans</option>
    <option value="Imagery">Imagery</option>
    <option value="ImageryClarity" selected>Imagery (Clarity)</option>
    <option value="ImageryFirefly">Imagery (Firefly)</option>
    <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
    <option value="DarkGray">Dark Gray</option>


    <option value="ShadedRelief">Shaded Relief</option>
    <option value="Physical">Physical</option>
  </select>
</div>
  </head>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='JS/maptest.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
// Define site URL
var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="JS/maptest.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'JS/maptest.js', '' );

//define icon image locations
var Sourceiconurl =  myURL + 'images/source.png',
    Blankiconurl =  myURL + 'images/blank.png',
    Unknowniconurl =  myURL + 'images/unknown.png', 
    Backgroundiconurl =  myURL + 'images/background.png';

//initialize variable   
var markers;

//pull data from json
jQuery.ajax({                              
url: myURL +  "map_json.php",
type: "JSON",
async: false,
success: function(data){
       markers = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       jQuery(markers).each(function( index, element ) {     

       });
} 
}); 

//initialize map
var map = L.map( 'map', {
  center: [39.8333333, -98.585522],
  minZoom: 1,
  zoom: 4
});

//create esri layers and selector
var layer = L.esri.basemapLayer('Imagery').addTo(map);
  var layerLabels = L.esri.basemapLayer('ImageryLabels');
      map.addLayer(layerLabels);

  function setBasemap(basemap) {
    if (layer) {
      map.removeLayer(layer);
    }

    layer = L.esri.basemapLayer(basemap);

    map.addLayer(layer);

    if (layerLabels) {
      map.removeLayer(layerLabels);
    }

    if (basemap === 'ShadedRelief'
     || basemap === 'Oceans'
     || basemap === 'Gray'
     || basemap === 'DarkGray'
     || basemap === 'Terrain'
   ) {
      layerLabels = L.esri.basemapLayer(basemap + 'Labels');
      map.addLayer(layerLabels);
    } else if (basemap.includes('Imagery')) {
      layerLabels = L.esri.basemapLayer('ImageryLabels');
      map.addLayer(layerLabels);
    }
  }

  function changeBasemap(basemaps){
    var basemap = basemaps.value;
    setBasemap(basemap);
  }

//create legend (need to figure out how to format)  
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend'),
        grades = ["Source", "Blank", "Background", "Unknown"],
        labels = [Sourceiconurl,Blankiconurl,Backgroundiconurl,Unknowniconurl];

    // loop through names and assign labels
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            grades[i] + (" <img src="+ labels[i] +" height='50' width='50'>") +'<br>';
    }

    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);

//define base icon features
 var MapIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [40, 55],
        iconAnchor:   [20, 35],
        popupAnchor:  [2, -10]
    }
}); 

//define custom icons 
var Source = new MapIcon({iconUrl: Sourceiconurl}),
    Blank = new MapIcon({iconUrl: Blankiconurl}),
    Unknown = new MapIcon({iconUrl: Unknowniconurl}), 
    Background = new MapIcon({iconUrl: Backgroundiconurl});

//allows function to read json field and assign to icon url 
var icons = {
    "Source": Source,
    "Blank": Blank,
    "Unknown": Unknown,
    "Background": Background};

//define clustering layer 
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup({});

//creates markers and popups for each json dataset
for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i )
{

  var popup = '<br/><b>Sample Name:</b> '+ markers[i]["Sample Name"] +
              '<br/><b>Location Description:</b> ' + markers[i]["Location Description"] +
              '<br/><b>Date Taken:</b> ' + markers[i]["Date"] +
              '<br/><b>Classification:</b> ' + markers[i]["Classification"]

  var m = L.marker( [markers[i].Lattitude, markers[i].Longitude], {icon: icons[markers[i]["Classification"]]})
                  .bindPopup( popup );

  markerClusters.addLayer( m );
}

map.addLayer( markerClusters );
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "Sample Name": "7411-2",
    "Date": "2017-09-05",
    "Lattitude": "40.3126",
    "Longitude": "-94.0277",
    "Location Description": "Lake 1",
    "Classification": "Unknown",
    "Empty": "1"
  },
  {
    "Sample Name": "7411-1",
    "Date": "2017-09-05",
    "Lattitude": "40.5999",
    "Longitude": "-93.7661",
    "Location Description": "Lake 2",
    "Classification": "Source",
    "Empty": "1"
  },
  {
    "Sample Name": "7406-3",
    "Date": "2017-07-31",
    "Lattitude": "39.4076",
    "Longitude": "-94.5555",
    "Location Description": "Lake 3",
    "Classification": "Blank",
    "Empty": "1"
  },
  {
    "Sample Name": "7406-3",
    "Date": "2017-07-31",
    "Lattitude": "39.4076",
    "Longitude": "-94.5555",
    "Location Description": "Lake 3",
    "Classification": "Background",
    "Empty": "1"
  }
]
```

ICONS

```
You can use any 4 .png icon files in place of the ones I have listed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ghybs, except that doesn't fully address what I am asking. (As in, I am unsure of how to incorporate the custom dynamic markers.) But the plugin you wrote looks like the ticket.

Comment: Make sure you split your question in separate issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545791/leaflet-map-getting-specific-data-of-geojson-file-with-button?noredirect=1&lq=1 should guide you on your first step. Feel free to open a new question with details of your specific issue should you still need help.

Comment: @ghybs I made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856490/jquery-leaflet-marker-layer-cluster-support-with-layers-generated-from-unique-js  I was able to get the dynamic layers, but now I'm struggling with your clustering plugin.